Is the core essential for wireless power transfer?
I am working on a pad for wireless power transmission as a college graduation project.
If you look at the papers, there are cases where the core is used, and there are cases where the litz wire is simply wrapped around the acrylic plate, isn't the core essential?
Trying to buy a core makes me hesitate because it's too expensive.
Please give me some advice.
I can't afford to buy a large core because my graduation project cost is only 200 dollars, and I think I can only buy a core that is about 100 x 100 x 15 mm. Can I make a transmitting/receiving pad without a core?

@kogyu You probably mean litz wire.

Unless you are operating in a vacuum, you already have a core: the so-called "air core". A real-life example is your NFC badge/coin which you hold close to the reader. "Close" can be in the range of several meters for anti-theft devices or in the range of a few centimeters for identification badges or keys. In any case, there's no ferromagnetic core inside the card/badge/coin/tag, but the energy transfer from the reader to the badge works nevertheless. -- Note that air (the oxygen actually) is paramagnetic, not ferromagnetic, but this has no practical implications here!

@Klaws given how close the electromagnetic properties of air are to those of a vacuum, an air core and no core come to the same thing anyway

Several things:

Wireless transfer is basically about dealing with the low \$k\$ of a loosely-coupled transformer.  Handle that, and it doesn't matter too much, for the power flow path, whether you use a core or not.  This quickly demands resonant solutions.
Conversely, anywhere you can avoid low-\$k\$ design, efficiency and cost are generally improved.  When \$k\$ is relatively large (say, >0.8?), a more conventional untuned or square-wave method becomes effective.  (Even at lower values say ~0.5, it can be practical, mainly if one has a means to solve output regulation.)
Core acts to increase inductance, and alter coupling.  In particular, it can be used to increase coupling to the load, and reduce coupling to unintended paths -- nearby circuitry or material -- it has shielding value too. A necessity on compact electronics like a cellphone.
Core doesn't have to be fancy. A typical non-contact charger might consist of two ferrite plates with pancake coils.  Ferrite plates are cheap and plentiful, for applications like this and general EMI shielding.  Note that, for a pancake geometry, features on the core face don't really matter (a very shallow "pot core" geometry plus some minimum distance between coils, has about the same airgap as with flat plates).


I can't afford to buy a large core because my graduation project cost is only 200 dollars, and I think I can only buy a core that is about 10010015. Can I make a transmitting/receiving pad without a core?

You didn't mention what power level you're working with, or what distance/alignment scales; I can only assume they are free variables, and I would simply suggest scaling down the problem to a size and power level that is tractable. (You might make it a point of your project that everything is scalable, so it isn't material to your conclusion to design to a given power level. This might not work so well if it's a worked example driven by a specific application.) For example, Laird MP1496-000 is under $2/ea at one US distributor.

Thank you so much! I didn't have this kind of core when I was looking for it, but only an expensive one

Additionally, a (ferromagnetic) core will limit the energy transfer as the core might reach saturation.

You do not need a core for your 2 coils to demonstrate wireless power transfer .In fact Rf transformers worked this way before ferrite cores appeared .The core will raise coupling coefficient putting more of the magnetic flux where it is wanted and less flux where it is not wanted .The core will mean that fewer turns are needed reducing litz wire costs .

So the core is simply used to increase the bonding coefficient on a small pad?
Conversely, if the size doesn't matter, there's a way to increase the coupling coefficient with a large number of turns without using the core, right?
